# UITextView set width and height in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder, uitextview

I have a UITextView with a cell that has a UILabel and a UITextView.  I am trying to set the width and height of the textview.  I do this in heightForRowAtIndexPath, but my UITextView is set to autosize the width in story builder.  When heightForRowAtIndexPath gets called and I find my UITextView its width is the value set in interface builder and not the "re-sized" width.

SO, how do I get the new size after auto-sizing?  My UITextVies is set to 280 in IB, but when I show it on an iPad the cell width is greater than 280, but in heightForRowAtIndexPath I still get 280.

Can anyone tell me hw to get the correct width after the autosize.

**UPDATE:**

To clarify, I am trying to set the height for the UITextView in the cell.  I am calling boundingRectWithSize, and I pass a height of CGFloatMax, but I need to set the width to the 'new autosized' width on the UITextView.  I am trying to figure out how to get that.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a screen shot of my Autosizing.  I have the UILabel and UITextView set the same way, with the width set to grow.

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure your width of cell is set to the value set in the method heightForRowAtIndexPath? because this function returns height before the cell is created.

Comment: in heightForRowAtIndexPath if I get the UITextView and check it's height and width they are the values set in IB.

Comment: Again i am saying this function returns height before the cell is created.

Comment: Correct, I posted an update to clarify a little better.  I am calculating a new hight based on the text.  This works great for iPhone because the width is fixed at 280 and it works perfect because I pass to boundingRectWithSize CGFLOATMAX for the height and 280 for the Width.  BUT, in iPhone, the UITextView gets autosized to a larger width.  I need that width.

Comment: post screenshot of your autoresizing struts and string or the constraints if you are using AutoLayout.

Comment: Added screenshot to my post.

Comment: set the right hand side spring too

Comment: I set the right hand and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` it's a delegate method for `UITableView` that defines the height for a `UITableViewCell`. If you're already setting the row height using [`UITableView.rowHeight`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/rowHeight) method or in Storyboard and your rows have static height, you don't need to implement it.

Assuming that your `UITextView` is contained in the `UITableView` (otherwise the row height and the textview height are ***not*** related), make sure that the [autoresizingMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) is correct.

Comment: My heights are dynamic.  The text is different in each cell so I need to calculate the height for each cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Can you share some code? If the cell height is correct, the problem is with the autoresizingMask. If the cell height is not correct, the problem may be with the height calculation.

Comment: I can post some code, but my height calculation is correct, but I need to provide a width to the boundingRectWithSize call and I do not know the "new" current width. That is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]};
        CGRect rect = [self.textview.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(textview_width, max_height) 
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin 
                                              attributes:attributes 
                                              context:nil];
return rect.size.height;
}
```

Comment: LOL, that is exactly what I want to do, BUT, I do not know how to get the Autosized width.

Answer (score -1):

I did this another way since no one was able to offer a bester solution.  I got the screen width and recalculated the position of my UITextView.  I also had to remove the autosizing settings for the UITextView.

Comment: In the screenshots the autoresizing mask is not correct, just as many of us suggested. But you just 'figured out' how to solve it because no one was able to offer a 'bester' solution... *sigh*

Comment: Hmmm, I did try changing the autosizing mask, but it did not seem to have any effect on the size I was getting in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method.  After looking at google and other stack overflow posts I came to the conclusion that maybe I am asking a foolish question since no sample or post had any reference to a width for UITextView or UILabel dynamic text height calculation in a cell view.